# what chords can I use for the V chord a ii V i minor progression?

Tags: chords

In a minor mode or minor key sequence, can the V chord be a minor chord, major chord or m7b5 chord?

Comment: Have you tried them? How did it go?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit mor details

Comment: In minor, V tends to be major, like for example V7b9, a very common chord for a tonal piece in a minor key. I may well be wrong here, but I think minor music not using the leading tone, that is, not using ♮7 of the "parent scale" (modal music for example), uses V less often. For example, a very typical "minor vamp", dorian in this case, is Im-IV-Im-IV... no V.

Answer (score 2):

The diatonic chord built on the 5th degree of the minor scale is a minor chord. For example, in C minor the 5 chord is v or G minor. G minor can be used in a chord progression in C minor but it doesn’t function as a dominant V chord. In order to establish a dominant to tonic relationship in minor keys the leading tone of the C scale or major 7th (B natural) is used creating a V or G, or a G7 if you’re using 4 note chords. This is the harmonic minor scale, a natural minor scale with a M7 instead of a m7.

A ii-V-I in C major is Dm7-G7-Cmaj7

A ii-V-i in C minor is Dm7b5-G7-Cm7.

Your question says “what chords can I use for the V chord...”. When creating a chord progression you can use any chords you want, there are no rules for creating music. However if you want to specifically play a ii-V-i then it should be done as above. There are some options though. Sometimes a non-diatonic iim7 (no flat 5) is used in a minor ii-V-i for variation or effect. Also there are often one or more upper tensions added to the V chord such as b9, #9, #11 and b13 in minor ii-V’s as well.

Answer (score 0):

V = major chord is the harmonic dominant

v = minor chord is the natural dominant (in Aeolian mode)

the minor7b5 I wouldn't use but the viidim.7 can be used as substitution of the V7b9 without root tone.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that that what you say about the v chord being a natural dominant in aeolian contradicts Johns answer above? John says that for it to be a dominant chord it has to have the raised 7th degree of the scale (leading tone). Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: Originally there was no augmented lead tone in aeolian minor. So the dominant would have been a minor chord. In the early medieval era there was theory of tonic and dominant. Event though already the gregorian chant had a *tenor* tone which was the 5th of the minor mode which was preceding the development of the dominant as this *repercussio* was a kind of *dominant* melodic tone.  The theory of a dominant as a major chord is close associated with the thinking in minor-major tonal system. But if you now say the dominant of aeolian mode has a major 3rd and thus no longer aeolian.